# How to include sorted navigation properties with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, linq, include

I have an entity `A` with a collection of `B` inside. I load them with a `_entity.A.Include(a => a.B)`

Now I want to have the B's into A sorted by a custom OrderBy. I tried `_entity.A.Include(a => a.B.OrderBy(o => o.Version)` but I get a :

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Version is an integer.

Comment: Can you post a body of your `OrderBy` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in this case you can try:

```
var list = _entity.A.Include("B").ToList();
list.ForEach(m => m.B = m.B.OrderBy(o => o.Version));
```

or:

```
_entity.A.Include("B").Select(m => new A {
        //some props,
        B = m.B.OrderBy(o => o.Version)
        });
```

Comment: Agree, but can this by done with just one query to avoid looping the collections twice?

Comment: @SoMoS I've added secound solution which have place in one line, but I'm not sure which is better.

Comment: Well, I'm not completely happy with the solution but I will accept it as I don't have other options. Thanks!